# Linux command usage

Tags: linux, shell, io-redirection

I use

```
./a.out <in >out
```

to take input from in file and writing output to out file while running a C++ program in Linux, but if I want to only write to out file then how will I do it using this?

Comment: If you write it as "./a.out <in >out" instead of "./a.out <in> out", perhaps it will be clearer. Just skip the "<in" part.

Comment: This is basic knowledge for using Linux/Unix. You should read some book about the matter in order to get the fundamental concepts. For instance, [The Linux Command Line](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php) (you can download it for free), chapter 6 is about input/output redirection.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the input has to come from *somewhere* so, if you leave off input redirection, it will come from the *current* standard input, most likely your terminal:

```
./a.out >out
```

If you want *no* input (or, more precisely, immediate end-of-file), you can read from the null device:

```
./a.out </dev/null >out
```

Comment: I think OP means he compiled another program to the unique name `a.out` that takes no input and he just wants to write the program output to `out` this time. You showed him how to do it, even if what `a.out` was had, or had not, changed.